# Remove Duplicates from multi case query in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, duplicates

I have the following query

```
 SELECT
    student.StudentID,
    student.`Name`,
    CASE
WHEN attendance.date = '2015-09-07' and attendance.StudentID IS NOT NULL THEN
    'Present'
ELSE
    'Absent'
END AS '2015-09-07',
 CASE
WHEN attendance.date = '2015-09-14' and attendance.StudentID IS NOT NULL THEN
    'Present'
ELSE
    'Absent'
END AS '2015-09-14'
FROM
    student
LEFT JOIN attendance ON student.StudentID = attendance.StudentID`
```

Which gives me the following result:

[image: Query Results]

I have tried using `GROUP BY student.StudentID` but then it gives me incorrect results. It shows 'Absent' in the '2015-09-14' column for 'k1052280' instead of present.

I am getting

[image]

and I want to get this result

[image]

> `CREATE TABLE`student`(`
>   StudentID`varchar(8) NOT NULL,`
>   Name`varchar(100) NOT NULL,`
>   Email`varchar(254) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,`
>   WorkshopID`int(4) NOT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (`StudentID`),
>     UNIQUE KEY`StudentID`(`StudentID`,`Email`),
>     KEY`WorkshopID`(`WorkshopID`),
>     CONSTRAINT`student_ibfk_1`FOREIGN KEY (`WorkshopID`) REFERENCES`workshop`(`WorkshopID`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`
>
> `CREATE TABLE`attendance`(`
>   AttendanceID`int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`
>   StudentID`varchar(8) NOT NULL,`
>   Date`date NOT NULL,`
>   Time`time NOT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (`AttendanceID`),
>     UNIQUE KEY`unique_index`(`StudentID`,`Date`),
>     CONSTRAINT`attendance_ibfk_1`FOREIGN KEY (`StudentID`) REFERENCES`student`(`StudentID`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=194 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`
>
> `INSERT INTO`student`VALUES ('k1052280', 'Ali Shaikh', 'k1052280@something.com', '101');
>   INSERT INTO`student`VALUES ('k1052287', 'McKenzie Roth', 'Quisque@penatibus.edu', '102');
>   INSERT INTO`student`VALUES ('k1052288', 'Dacey Sullivan', 'sollicitudin.adipiscing.ligula@semmollisdui.com', '103');
>   INSERT INTO`student`VALUES ('k1052289', 'Callie Williamson', 'elementum@orciPhasellus.com', '104');
>   INSERT INTO`student`VALUES ('k1052290', 'Savannah Hyde', 'nec.metus.facilisis@nonummyut.co.uk', '101');
>   INSERT INTO`student`VALUES ('k1052291', 'Paul Tyson', 'semper.erat.in@ipsumleoelementum.net', '102');
>   INSERT INTO`student`VALUES ('k1052292', 'Nerea Ramos', 'gravida.sagittis.Duis@lacinia.edu', '103');
>   INSERT INTO`student`VALUES ('k1052293', 'Mark Mills', 'pellentesque.massa@blanditviverra.co.uk', '104');
>   INSERT INTO`student`VALUES ('k1052294', 'Zelda Cantu', 'ut@fringillaporttitorvulputate.org', '101');`
>
> `INSERT INTO`attendance`VALUES ('168', 'k1052280', '2015-09-07', '00:00:00');
>   INSERT INTO`attendance`VALUES ('169', 'k1052287', '2015-09-09', '00:00:00');
>   INSERT INTO`attendance`VALUES ('170', 'k1052288', '2015-09-11', '00:00:00');
>   INSERT INTO`attendance`VALUES ('171', 'k1052289', '2015-09-11', '00:00:00');
>   INSERT INTO`attendance`VALUES ('172', 'k1052290', '2015-09-14', '00:00:00');
>   INSERT INTO`attendance`VALUES ('173', 'k1052291', '2015-09-16', '00:00:00');
>   INSERT INTO`attendance`VALUES ('174', 'k1052292', '2015-09-18', '00:00:00');
>   INSERT INTO`attendance`VALUES ('175', 'k1052293', '2015-09-18', '00:00:00');
>   INSERT INTO`attendance`VALUES ('176', 'k1052294', '2015-09-21', '00:00:00');
>   INSERT INTO`attendance`VALUES ('177', 'k1052295', '2015-09-23', '00:00:00');
>   INSERT INTO`attendance`VALUES ('178', 'k1052296', '2015-09-25', '00:00:00');
>   INSERT INTO`attendance`VALUES ('179', 'k1052297', '2015-09-25', '00:00:00');
>   INSERT INTO`attendance`VALUES ('183', 'k1052288', '2015-09-14', '00:00:00');
>   INSERT INTO`attendance`VALUES ('187', 'k1052290', '2015-09-07', '00:00:00');
>   INSERT INTO`attendance`VALUES ('188', 'k1052280', '2015-09-21', '10:30:00');
>   INSERT INTO`attendance`VALUES ('193', 'k1052280', '2015-04-05', '00:00:00');`

Comment: What results do you want to see?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to see Present if they are present and absent if they are absent on each of those dates

Comment: You still haven't given us a rule for how to choose between the two rows with `k1052280`.  Please explain your logic.

Comment: How can the student "Savannah" be "Absent" AND "Present" at same time ? There is something wrong on your logic.

Comment: The table is wrong, you shouldn't have multiple entries for a person, I think you need to change the initial query so  it will only return you one line per person

Comment: And the query to fix the problem with your schema would be very complex for what should be a simple query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Is there any other way I can achieve this? If not in Mysql  then PHP?

Comment: Perhaps it should be an inner join instead of a left join

Comment: @Pete That did not work :(

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you help with this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this query would work-

```
 SELECT Student.StudentID, Student.NAME, IF ( ( SELECT distinct 1 FROM attendance WHERE attendance.StudentID = student.StudentID AND date = '2015-09-07' ) = 1, 'Present', 'Absent' ) AS '2015-09-07', IF ( ( SELECT distinct 1 FROM attendance WHERE attendance.StudentID = student.StudentID AND date = '2015-09-14' ) = 1, 'Present', 'Absent' ) AS '2015-09-14' FROM student as student;
```

Example-
You can use sub query in colums like this.

Create Table: CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Create Table: CREATE TABLE `attend` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `stud_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `stud_id` (`stud_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `attend_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`stud_id`) REFERENCES `student` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

insert the data-

INSERT INTO `student` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'hitesh'), (2, 'mundra'), (3, 'sumit'), (4, 'ashish');
 INSERT INTO `attend` (`id`, `stud_id`, `date`) VALUES (1, 1, '05-04-2015'), (2, 1, '05-04-2015'), (3, 1, '06-04-2015'), (4, 1, '06-04-2015'), (5, 2, '05-04-2015'), (6, 3, '05-04-2015'), (7, 3, '05-04-2015'), (8, 4, '06-04-2015');

the resultant query

```
 select id , name , if((select distinct 1 from attend where stud_id=s.id and date = '05-04-2015')=1,'Present','Absent') as '05-04-2015' ,if((select distinct 1 from attend where stud_id=s.id and date = '06-04-2015')=1, 'Present' , 'Absent') as '06-04-2015' from student as s;
```

Comment: I modified to use it with my db and I get this error [Err] 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: use this query---  select id , name , if((select distinct 1 from attend where stud_id=s.id and date = '05-04-2015')=1,'Present','Absent') as '05-04-2015' ,if((select distinct 1 from attend where stud_id=s.id and date = '06-04-2015')=1, 'Present' , 'Absent') as '06-04-2015' from student as s;

Comment: I tried this but I get another problem the query is not displaying the correct results, first column is present and second column is absent for all the records. the query I used it --- 'SELECT
 Student.StudentID,
 Student.NAME,

IF (
 (
  SELECT
   distinct 1
  FROM
   attendance
  WHERE
   attendance.StudentID = StudentID
  AND date = '2015-04-05'
 ) = 1,
 'Present',
 'Absent'
) AS '05-04-2015',

IF (
 (
  SELECT
   distinct 1
  FROM
   attendance
  WHERE
   attendance.StudentID = StudentID
  AND date = '2015-04-7'
 ) = 1,
 'Present',
 'Absent'
) AS '06-04-2015'
FROM student as student'

Comment: check the date value  in second column. this is not matching any value , i mean condition is not satisfying. write appropriate condition in inner sub query. I have tested and its working well.

Comment: I changed the date but the problem is it's saying that make everyone present if one person matches the condition thus making everyone present in the date columns

Comment: i have edit my ans and tested with this data. if still you have problem then post you create, insert table query like me. i will try.

Comment: SELECT Student.StudentID, Student.NAME, IF ( ( SELECT distinct 1 FROM attendance WHERE attendance.StudentID = student.StudentID AND date = '2015-09-07' ) = 1, 'Present', 'Absent' ) AS '2015-09-07', IF ( ( SELECT distinct 1 FROM attendance WHERE attendance.StudentID = student.StudentID AND date = '2015-09-14' ) = 1, 'Present', 'Absent' ) AS '2015-09-14' FROM student as student;

Comment: This solved it perfectly and it works nicely in PHP too. I am able to add as many dates as I want. I can't thank you enough. Much apreciated